# Grid step (difference between two adjacent machine-representable numbers

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I wrote such a code to find the grid step(difference between two adjacent machine-representable numbers, machine epsilon the difference between the minimum machine-representable number greater than one and one). Why does this program show 1 for huge values ​​of x and how to fix it to show the correct answer?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    long double x,eps=1.0,a; 
    scanf("%Lg",&x);
    do
    {
        a=eps;
        eps/=2.0;
    }
    while( x+eps>x);
    printf("Grid step: %Le",(long double)a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not tag C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two different languages.

Comment: sorry. c and c++ is very near languages , because i write

Comment: Please pick one to keep and delete the other tag. Although this question is not particularly about C or C++ at all; you could add floating-point tags [floating-point] and [ieee-754] and delete the language tags (but mention in the question that C or C++ code is being used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating-point numbers are represented as a sign (+1 or −1) *s*, an exponent *e*, and a numeral *f* with a fixed number of digits in a fixed base (called the significand). With base *b* and precision (number of digits) *p*, the number represented with sign *s*, exponent *e*, and digits *f*<sub>0</sub>, *f*<sub>−1</sub>, *f*<sub>−2</sub>, *f*<sub>−3</sub>, *f*<sub>−4</sub>,… *f*<sub>1−*p*</sub> is *s*•*b*<sup>*e*</sup>•sum(*f*<sub>*i*</sub>•*b*<sup>*i*</sup> for −*p* < i ≤ 0).

For example, with base 2, precision 4, sign +1, exponent 1, and significand 1.001, the number represented is +1•2<sup>1</sup>•1.001<sub>2</sub> = 2•1⅛ = 2¼ = 9/4 = 2.25.

Given any representable number within bounds, the next representable number of greater magnitude is obtained by adding 1 to the lowest digit of the significand. With the above example, the next greater number would have significand 1.010 and the same sign and exponent, so it would be +1•2<sup>1</sup>•1.010<sub>2</sub> = 2•1¼ = 2½ = 10/4 = 2.5.

This means that, if a number `x` is represented with exponent *e*, then the difference between it and the next greater magnitude representable number is *b*<sup>*e*</sup>•*b*<sup>1−*p*</sup> = *b*<sup>*e*+1−*p*</sup>.

The number 1 is represented with exponent 0, since 1 = +1•*b*<sup>0</sup>•1.000…000<sub>*b*</sub>. So the difference between 1 and the next representable number is *b*<sup>1−*p*</sup>. If your `long double` format has a base of two and a precision of 64 digits (bits), then this difference is 2<sup>1−64</sup> = 2<sup>−63</sup>, so the value of the so-called “machine epsilon” should be 2<sup>−63</sup>.

If a binary format is being used, then 2 is represented with an exponent of 1, so the difference between it and the next representable number is *b*<sup>*e*+1−*p*</sup> = 2<sup>1+1−64</sup> = 2<sup>−62</sup>. These differences are called ULP, units of least precision.

The ULP for 4 is 2<sup>−61</sup>, for 8 is 2<sup>−60</sup>, and so on. For 2<sup>63</sup>, the ULP is 2<sup>63−63</sup> = 1.

When you enter a number that is 2<sup>64</sup> or larger, your program fails to find the ULP because the ULP is larger than 1, but your program starts looking at 1 and works downward.

You can fix it either by starting with the largest possible ULP in your `long double` format or by changing the program to work either upward or downward, depending on the value of `x`.

Comment: and how can i fix this ? Do you know ?

Comment: i wanna that this program work for any values. But now this program gives me on the screen 1.0000... when i write big value